# jQuery clone crashes when using multiple classes

Tags: jquery, html, class, clone, draggable

I have multiple classes, and when I use the clone helper with the draggable option it only works once. I believe it is because I misuse the classes. Could anyone point out my mistake or give me a tutorial?

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".icon").draggable( {
        containment: 'document',
        helper: 'clone',
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="icon news">
    <img class="image" src="news.png"><br/>news
</div>
<div class="icon about">
    <img class="image" src="about.png"><br/>about
</div>
```

It somehow works if I don't use clone. Can I fake my own clone with a function? Call for `$(this)` element and make it `opacity .7`?

Comment: Do you want the element to be cloned or not? You can change opacity directly, with `opacity` option.

Comment: I want each div to be a clone of them selves, so they both get individual pictures.